# Scatter plot grid faceted by columns in matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make a faceted scatterplot with Python (I know how I would've done this in R but I'm a newbie when it comes to Python...).
  I have a df like this fake one:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    [['Alex',10, 2, 2, 6],['Bob',12, 6, 5, 1],['Clark',13, 5, 3, 5]],columns=[
        'Name','Fruits', 'Apples', 'Bananas', 'Citrus'])
```

and I would like to make a scatter plot with the relations between each fruit and the sum of fruits for each 'Name, i.e. Fruits and Apples, Fruits and Bananas, Fruits and Citrus.
For example the scatterplot with the relations between Fruits and Apples would be the one produced by this code:

```
plt.scatter(df[['Apples']], df[['Fruits']])
```

Is there any convenient way of doing this?

Comment: You need to clarify what "scatter plot with the relations" means.

Comment: @Bazingaa Clearer?

Comment: Fruits column is just a sum of other 3 columns. Do you want to plot one curve each for Alex, Bob and Clark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seaborn's FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) is just what you're looking for. Seaborn usually works best with long-dfs too.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#create a long df, with columns for name, total fruit, and rows for specific fruit counts
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name', 'Fruits'], value_vars=['Apples','Bananas','Citrus'], var_name='Fruit_Type', value_name='Count')

g = sns.FacetGrid(df_melt, col="Name",  col_wrap = 2, hue = "Fruit_Type")
g = g.map(plt.scatter, "Count", "Fruits")
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for but the code gave me this Key error ` "None of [Index(['Fruit_Type', 'Fruit'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: It was just the df name in the grid-code (and an s at the end of fruits). Thank you very much.

Comment: You can also use the FacetGrid argument 'hue' to change the color of observations based on a column. To be clear though, this visualization doesn't look very good because of the small sample size. I'm not sure this is the best example to learn the power of Seaborn's FacetGrid.

Comment: This is "faceted" by name. If I wanted to have the hue as names and have the ratio fruit_type/fruits as the "facet" - How do I do then? (I am sorry for the r-lingo I am not sure what it's called in python)

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally understand your question, but the 'col' argument in sns.FacetGrid will define what subset of the data each chart should contain, the 'hue' argument can point towards a _category_ column that can be used to color instances.

Comment: Thank you. I think I've got it now. The real data frame is larger and it looks great.